How do I manage Dio in Flutter projects using Riverpod
Let's say we have API and we want to manage all api with Dio. How can I create base Dio options?
I want to under control api response errors, connection timeouts etc. What is the best way to connecting API with Dio using Riverpod?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I think you could start from the easiest way to use riverpod :
final dioProvider = Provider<Dio>((ref) => Dio());

In this manner you define a provider used globally that does not create a  new Dio() object every time.
Then, you can add some stuff like this:
   class MyDioUseCase {
     final Dio dio;
     MyDioUseCase(this.dio);

     void request() async {
       Response response;
      response = await dio.get('/test?id=12&name=dio');
      print(response.data.toString());
      // The below request is the same as above.
      response = await dio.get(
        '/test',
        queryParameters: {'id': 12, 'name': 'dio'},
      );
      print(response.data.toString());
    }
}

@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
Dio dioProvider(DioProviderRef ref) => Dio();

@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
Dio myDioUseCase(MyDioUseCaseRef ref) => MyDioUseCase (ref.watch(dioProvider));

